# HQL query not working, Incorrect syntax near ',' error. Using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, hql

I am trying to execute following update query and getting error,

Query is=

```
@Transactional
public List<Order> getClosedOrders(String userID) throws DataAccessException {
try { 

String SQL_SELECT_QUERY = "from Order as o where o.orderStatus='closed' and o.account.profile.userId='"+userID+"'";

String SQL_UPDATE_QUERY = "update Order set orderStatus=completed where orderStatus=closed and account.profile.userId='"+userID+"'";

List<Order> orderList = (List<Order>) list(SQL_SELECT_QUERY); 

if(!orderList.isEmpty()) {

batchUpdate(SQL_UPDATE_QUERY);
return orderList;
}
return null;
} catch(Exception ex) {

ex.printStackTrace();
throw new DataAccessException(errorMessage);
} 
}
```

However Select query is working but
 for Update query it is giving
 Following error:

> WARN [http-8080-2]
>   (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:71) - SQL
>   Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
>
> ERROR [http-8080-2]
>   (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:72) -
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not execute update query
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:84)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:334)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:209)

I don't understand why this is happening. I am not using "," anywhere in my query but still it says that incorrect syntax near','
Why it is so? How to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is indeed strange. Only thing that comes to mind is that userID contains a comma, but i'm sure you checked that.

Comment: Try to log genereated SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

```
<property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true"></property>
```

It will help you a lot.

Second of all:

```
String SQL_UPDATE_QUERY = "update Order set orderStatus=completed where orderStatus=closed and account.profile.userId=:userId";
```

and use

```
addString("userId",userId);
```

May be these changes will help you to eliminate problem.

Comment: Added that property but don't know why its not showing queries.

Comment: "update Order set orderStatus=completed where orderStatus=closed and account.profile.userId='"+userID+"'"; This query I want to execute.

Comment: @Sugar, this is HQL query, and what about SQL query? you shoul enable hibernate.show.sql and then see original SQL query in console.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure but try to escape `Order` by backticks (for MySQL) or double quotes (for PostgreSQL) or similar. If your query uses as raw SQL then database may recognize it as reserved keyword (like `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes in this one

```
String SQL_UPDATE_QUERY = "update Order set orderStatus=completed where orderStatus=closed and account.profile.userId='"+userID+"'";
```

Shouldn't it actually be

```
String SQL_UPDATE_QUERY = "update Order set orderStatus='completed' where orderStatus='closed' and account.profile.userId='"+userID+"'";
```

Quotes for all orderStatus expressions.